# Symfony PHPUnit self::$kernel is null in second test

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I am trying to create a PHPunit test accessing services from the container in symfony. To do so I call `self::bootKernel` in `setUpBeforeClass`. In the first test, the `self::$kernel` is ok, but the second test `self::$kernel` is null.

This is a simple test to check it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class KernelTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public static function setUpBeforeClass(): void
    {
        self::bootKernel();
    }

    public function testMethod1(){
        $this->assertNotNull(self::$kernel);
    }

    public function testMethod2(){
        $this->assertNotNull(self::$kernel);
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
$ bin/phpunit tests/KernelTest.php 
PHPUnit 7.5.18 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Notice: Undefined index: warnings in /app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php on line 334

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php on line 334

Testing App\Tests\KernelTest
.F                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 58 ms, Memory: 16.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) App\Tests\KernelTest::testMethod2
Failed asserting that null is not null.

/app/tests/KernelTest.php:19

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
```

As you can see, the second test fails the assertion.

This is the version that I am running of phpunit:

```
phpunit/phpunit                     8.5.2      The PHP Unit Testing framework.
symfony/phpunit-bridge              v5.0.2     Symfony PHPUnit Bridge
```

What I am doing wrong? Should I boot kernel in each test? I would like to boot it only once.

Comment: I think you should reboot the kernel for each test method. If you want to reuse the kernel, just merge the test methods into one test method (you can use other methods not called `test...` and just call them in a combined `testAll` method, of course). the kernel assumes it's clean when it's confronted with a new request, what tests usually test, so it's reasonable to kill the kernel after a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a look at the definition of the `WebTestCase`, for example through [GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/WebTestCase.php): in its `tearDown` method, the parent `tearDown` of the `KernelTestCase` (see [GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php) once more) is called, and this forces a shutdown of the kernel. As `tearDown` is called after each invididual test, booting the kernel once before all other tests does not help.

[Symfony's own documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html) boots the kernel in `setUp` (happening right before each individual test case), so that looks reasonable to me.

If you fear performance issues, keep in mind that such integration tests should not be used everywhere. By following the usual testing pyramid, you should have lots of unit tests (testing small parts of your code in isolation), less tests for coupled classes (where you could mock depending parts), and only a few test cases covering the whole system

Comment: Thank you, I will boot up the kernel in setUp then, and be sure as you have said to have as few as tests as possible dealing with kernel.

Comment: Have fun testing :) The second part is only a recommendation to be thought of - it's still better to have many integration tests (running the whole stuff using the container and kernel) than having none after all ;)